# Problem with the Same Number in 'Code Generator`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I made a simple app in **Laravel** and I can use it but, I have two problems with numbers:

Once I had the same invoice numbers, for example `10/2019` and `10/2019` (but different id of course) in `MySQL` and, today, I have invoice number `1/2019`, so I assume my app had null.

I'm looking for ways to protect myself against such problems.

My code:

```
$year = date('Y');
$newInvoice->yearly_counter = Invoice::whereYear('issued_at', $year)->max('yearly_counter') + 1;
```

Comment: Can you please share also migration and model?

Comment: i would research race conditions, because that seams to be happend when looking into this small code example..

Comment: `$newInvoice->yearly_counter = Invoice::whereYear('issued_at', $year)->max('yearly_counter') + 1;`   is not very smart to generate a new id on the application side to be used for inserting later (i assume)..  You need to do it completly in the RDMS to prevent race conditions..

Comment: I have red a little about it and I use ```DB::beginTransaction();

    $newInvoice = new Invoice; (...) DB::commit();``` is it solve problem?

Comment: If you create a unique key between `issued_at` and `yearly_counter` , and do your `save()` in a `try/catch` block, you can increase number and retry on faillure

Comment: no `DB::beginTransaction() \ DB::commit();` will not correctly handle this.. As you should not be generating a id on the client.. when two clients request this code at around the same time they will end up with the same id..

Comment: I've tried to improve the overall appearance and impact of your post, with some simple format and grammar modifications.

Comment: I can't make this row unique because I add in this table different type of documents where I add in type for exapmple correction/incoming_invoice and every of this documents could have this same number 1/2019, I looking for different solution. I'am open to paid for this solution email azbroja@outlook.com